# SVN Commit specific files

Tags: svn, terminal

Is there any way to commit only a list of specific files (e.q. just one of the list of files that SVN wants to commit).

I'm working on MAC OS X under Terminal, without any UI.

Answer (score 358, accepted):

Sure. Just list the files:

```
$ svn ci -m "Fixed all those horrible crashes" foo bar baz graphics/logo.png
```

I'm not aware of a way to tell it to ignore a certain set of files. Of course, if the files you do want to commit are easily listed by the shell, you can use that:

```
$ svn ci -m "No longer sets printer on fire" printer-driver/*.c
```

You can also have the svn command read the list of files to commit from a file:

```
$ svn ci -m "Now works" --targets fix4711.txt
```

Comment: so, basically, i should name the files explicitly? i can't just say don't touch this particular file?

Comment: you could do: svn st | cut -c 9- > targets.txt , then edit the targets.txt file to remove the specific file and use the --targets parameter to specify the filelist.

Comment: I think my new challenge is to *create* a bug which sets the printer on fire.

Comment: It is pathetic and ridiculous alike. No staging area. ```svn add``` is used to add files to repositories.

Answer (score 82):

Use changelists.  The advantage over specifying files is that you can visualize and confirm everything you wanted is actually included before you commit.

```
$ svn changelist fix-issue-237 foo.c 
Path 'foo.c' is now a member of changelist 'fix-issue-237'.
```

That done, svn now keeps things separate for you.  This helps when you're juggling multiple changes

```
$ svn status
A       bar.c
A       baz.c

--- Changelist 'fix-issue-237':
A       foo.c
```

Finally, tell it to commit what you wanted changed.

```
$ svn commit --changelist fix-issue-237 -m "Issue 237"
```

Comment: +1 for on point answer. Changelists are really the way to go!

Comment: If you want to add new directories to a changelist, don't forget to use svn add first, then use `svn changelist fix-issue-237 --recursive path/to/directory`

Comment: Actually changelists cannot be used with new directories.... "Subversion doesn't currently support the use of changelists with directories. "

Comment: @fschmengler:  SVN is a horrible tool.  I was just trying to make the best of the bad job it does.  Switch to git.  :P

Comment: I switched to Git many years ago and never looked back. Was forced to use svn again for a client, it feels like running with ball and chain at both legs

Comment: Almost like Git's staging area! Only so much more cumbersome. But really good to know if one's forced to work with arcane tools like Subversion.

Answer (score 42):

You basically put the files you want to commit on the command line

```
svn ci file1 file2 dir1/file3
```

Comment: so, basically, i should name the files explicitly? i can't just say don't touch this particular file?

Comment: if run without arguments svn commits all changed files
if run with a file as argument this file is commited
if run with a directory all changed files in the directory are commited

Answer (score 23):

Due to my subversion state, I had to get creative.  `svn st` showed `M`,`A` and `~` statuses.  I only wanted `M` and `A` so...

```
svn st | grep ^[A\|M] | cut -d' ' -f8- > targets.txt
```

This command says find all the lines output by `svn st` that start with `M` or `A`, cut using space delimiter, then get colums 8 to the end.  Dump that into targets.txt and overwrite.

Then modify targets.txt to prune the file list further.  Then run below to commit:

```
svn ci -m "My commit message" --targets targets.txt
```

Probably not the most common use case, but hopefully it helps someone.

Comment: You could also use `grep -v '^~'` to blacklist what you want.

Answer (score 10):

Besides listing the files explicitly as shown by [unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516188/1516189#1516189) and [Wienczny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516188/1516194#1516194), you can setup change lists and checkin these. These allow you to manage disjunct sets of changes to the same working copy.

You can read about them in the [online version of the excellent SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.changelists).

Answer (score 7):

try this script..

```
#!/bin/bash
NULL="_"
for f in `svn st|grep -v ^\?|sed s/.\ *//`; 
     do LIST="${LIST} $f $NULL on"; 
done
dialog --checklist "Select files to commit" 30 60 30 $LIST 2>/tmp/svnlist.txt
svn ci `cat /tmp/svnlist.txt|sed 's/"//g'`
```

Answer (score 2):

I make a (sub)folder named "hide", move the file I *don't* want committed to there.
Then do my commit, ignoring complaint about the missing file.
Then move the hidden file from hide back to ./

I know of no downside to this tactic.